# Probability of a Handshake between Individuals from Different Countries

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a circular table where a group of people is seated. The table consists of $x$ individuals from country A and $y$ individuals from country B. The seating arrangement is uniformly random. Each person from country A only shakes hands with other people from country A, while each person from country B only shakes hands with others from country B. Furthermore, each person only shakes hands with the person seated to their left or right. What is the probability that a handshake will occur between any two randomly chosen individuals?

Here is my solution:

The probability of a handshake is the product of the probability of two people sitting next to each other and the probability of them being from the same country. The probability of two people sitting next to each other is $\frac{x+y}{\binom{x+y}{2}}$, and the probability of them being from the same country is $\frac{\binom{x}{2}+\binom{y}{2}}{\binom{x+y}{2}}$. Therefore, the probability of a handshake is:

$$\frac{x+y}{\binom{x+y}{2}}\cdot \frac{\binom{x}{2}+\binom{y}{2}}{\binom{x+y}{2}} = \frac{2(x(x-1)+y(y-1))}{(x+y)(x+y-1)^2}$$

Does my calculation look correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: You talk about probabilities without having introduced any probabilistic setting. Usually I'd assume that this is because you forgot to state that the people are randomly arranged around the table with equal probability for each configuration. But on that assumption "the probability of them being from the same country" wouldn't make any sense, since whether two people are from the same country doesn't depend on where they sit. So I'm afraid you're going to have to explicitly state the probabilistic setting you're assuming for this to make sense.

Comment: Thanks, @joriki Sorry for the confusion. I edited the problem description.

Comment: Calculation does not work. Good idea to try small values in these situations to test. For example, $x=2$, $y=2$ yields probability $\frac29$, where you can compute the configurations by hand to verify that the probability should be $\frac23$

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Alborz. I appreciate your help. I was able to simulate the scenario in Python and obtained a probability of $2/9$ for the case where $x=y=2$. Would you mind sharing your calculation with me?

Comment: @Alex my apologies, my earlier comment is actually not correct.  I worked out the same formula that you got. Looks good!

Comment: Thanks @Alborz !